# sybase 'drop procedure'. can I get it to take a parameter instead of a naked proc name?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sybase

Happy Monday o/

I'm looking to do the following within a stored proc

```
  select @parameter="fooproc"
  drop procedure @parameter
```

instead of

```
  drop procedure fooproc
```

But it's choking with a syntax error.  Is there some way I can bend this to my will? I would've expected to be able to do this.

I've tried a few permutations of type declaration of @parameter to no avail.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @sql = STR_REPLACE('drop procedure {@parameter}', '{@parameter}', @parameter)

EXEC ( @sql )
```

I like to validate object names against database metadata before doing things like this.  This protects against errors up front and even injection in the later dynamic section.

i.e. something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = @parameter)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(2000)
    SELECT @sql = STR_REPLACE('drop procedure {@parameter}', '{@parameter}', @parameter)
    EXEC ( @sql )
END
```

Comment: Almost ;) in sybase it's: STR_REPLACE.

( In the interest of brevity, I left out the part where I did the validation, since that works ;-) 


Thanks o/

Comment: @Michael Wilson I thought for sure they'd be the same on both dialects of Transact-SQL ;-)

Comment: A perfectly reasonable assumption ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure ' || @parameter;
```